# apex:composition vs. apex:page

Tags: force.com-sites, caching, page-template

Let's say I have a "by-the-textbook" vf page, using apex:composition and a template:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false">

<apex:composition template = "template">
    Salesforce is crazy!!
</apex:composition>
```

And then I have a template, which is just another page.

What happens if the apex:page has conflicting properties?  For example, the page is cache="true" and the template is cache="false"  Who wins?

With a template without a cache value, I would still get the PRAGMA / NO CACHE and an expires meta tag dating back to Margaret Thatcher's days as PM.

As long as those are present, the browser won't keep any images/scripts or even CDN references it already downloaded.

Seems that I have to set the template cache to true to get those to disappear.  Is there a way to determine cache settings at the page level instead of for the whole site?

Cache was just my example...obviously there are other apex:page attributes that could conflict between page and template, so what determines what wins?

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is a hypothesis based on available documentation; if the results are important to you I would suggesting creating some tests in a dev org.

According to the [reference entry for `apex:include`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm), the include tag is "a component that inserts a second Visualforce page into the current page. **The entire page subtree is injected into the Visualforce DOM at the point of reference** and the scope of the included page is maintained" (emphasis mine).

I read that to mean that while processing the outer VF page, at the point that an `apex:include` tag is encountered, the system evaluates the included page, and then injects its content into the VF page that it is constructing.  Based on this reading, I would assume that any page-level settings such as cache control are wholly controlled by the outer page; the outer page has already begun being constructed and the headers are likely already constructed by the time the included page is evaluated.

Comment: The composition/template doesn't use the include tag.  It uses insert and define tags.